# How to avoid iframe callback in ASP.NET Masterpage

Tags: javascript, asp.net, iframe, master-pages

I am developing a .Net web application. I am using masterpage with iframes, the source of one of those iframe is a separate ASP page. This ASP page is dynamically changed on client side.

How do I can keep these changes after callback (exp navigation to other pages or refresh). Nothing that I tried the update panel, but seems does not work properly with masterpage. Is there any solution to load the page again after the refresh or to avoid the callback of this iframe?

Answer (score 0):

Anytime you change source of the iframe client-side save url into cookies then write javascript function on master page and run it when document is loaded ($(document).ready). In that function check if there is cookie with url and set iframe's src to be this url.

Comment: you may got me wrongly.what is changed is not the source of this page, but the page itself, there is a table in this page where the client can amend this table by adding new tr and td and many other controls that are changed client side. so i need to keep those changes after refresh or to avoid refreshing this iframe since is not the maincontent

Comment: OK, now I get what you need to achieve. Do you want to persist content of the iframe between postback only or between navigation too?

Comment: On both navigation and postback